# ZipInputStream and OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, out-of-memory, zip, zipinputstream

I'm facing an OutOfMemoryError when reading a zip file of 6 MB (25 MB uncompressed). I only have the error when getting the stream by iterating through the entries, not if I use `ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipEntry)`.

For example, this is working :

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
ZipEntry entry = zip.getEntry("file.xml");

InputStream is = zip.getInputStream(entry);

// Do stuff with is (loading the xml file in memory)
```

And this is not :

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();

while(entry != null) {
    if(entry.getName().equals("file.xml")) {
        // Do stuff with zis (loading the xml file in memory)
    }
    entry = zis.getNextEntry();
}
zis.close();
```

Does anyone knows why ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Are you using any specific Xmx when running?

Comment: Have you tried to call zis.closeEntry before calling zis.getNextEntry? (Closes the current ZIP entry and positions the stream for reading the next entry.)

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Thomas, the stack won't help, I get the OOM on a string split (the file is a KML file with lots of big polylines, I use the split to get each coordinates).
hveiga, I did not specify any xmx, I'm using Eclipse.
Sami, I just tried, it did not change anything. I may be wrong, but getNextEntry() call closeEntry() no ? Moreover my zip only contains the big file.

Comment: Does it actually run out of memory in the posted form? From your above comment it sounds like it happens in your processing code...

Comment: Yes, it happens in my code, but I use exactly the same code in both cases :/ .